# Scala Anorm Query Exception Handling

Tags: scala, anorm

I would like to understand how to best handle exceptions with Anorm using Scala's Try and match features

Given a query

```
database.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("Select 1").execute()
}
```

How would I catch exceptions ? I imagine something like

```
match {
   case Success(?) => ?
   case Failure(ex) => println(ex) ? 
}
```

Any working example would be much appreciated. I'd like to be able to handle any unexpected database related exceptions gracefully.

Comment: There are some examples [here](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2012/12/27/error-handling-in-scala/) and [here](https://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-exceptions/). May be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

The `withConnection`, `withTransaction` etc. methods' return values depends on the code block you're running.

In your example, you call the `.execute()` method which returns a Boolean. i.e. `true` for Success and `false` for a Failure.

If you want a more detailed result in case of executions, you could use `.executeQuery()` instead